# Can you use a var in jQuery to change the a tag so you can use 2 different URLs

Tags: jquery

With the following HTML , and using jQuery , can i tell which URL to open based on the different classes. I have 2 links within each li class , "homepage" and "depth" , can i use jQuery to force either only one to open based on a var set ?

Example

```
<div class="nflteampage">              
  <div class="box">                        
    <ul class="boxlink">  
     <li class="team bills">                                
      <a href="http://www.buffalobills.com/" title="Buffalo Bills" class="homepage" target="_blank"><span></span></a> 
      <a href="http://espn.go.com/nfl/team/depth/_/name/buf/buffalo-bills" title="Buffalo Bills" class="depth" target="_blank"><span></span></a> 
     </li>                       
    </ul>                            
  </div>
</div>
```

```
var = useDepth
```

or set

```
var = useHomepage
```

I want the user to be able to simple choose which var , and have the link open for either "homepage" or "depth"

Comment: can you provide js fiddle what do u want to do?

Comment: i dont know jquery , so it wouldn't help to set up a fiddle , just looking to be able to choose between the url wrapped in a.homepage or a.depth

Comment: your `var` can't decide without conditions, which you haven't explained

Comment: the only condition would be choosing from the 2 different URLs , if i set a var to "depth" i would like the link to direct there , and if i were to set a var to "homepage" i would like the link to open to that URL

Comment: please check this jsfiddle example you want like this? http://jsfiddle.net/mz_arain08/sut7vwb5/1/

Comment: thanks but not what i was looking for, i wanted to place both urls in the HTML , then use jQuery to set a var on which link to use , the depth or homepage link

Comment: your explanation is very lacking in detail. You want pairs of links to go to same url depending on variable set in JS?

Comment: in HTML i want each li class to have to a class links , each a class would have a unique class , then in jQuery simply be able to set a var to use either of the 2 links

Comment: @MShack please read again your own question with different eyes. It's not clear at ALL what you're trying to do here.

Comment: `"which a tag url to direct to "` ??? `"I have the URL directing to a class="homepage" url "` ??? `"What i was wondering is there i way i can inject 2 different URLs"` ???(whattt) `"decide which set of urls you wanted to use based on the a tag class "` ??? `"this way i can reuse the same html/css and allow the var to let the user decide if they wish to direct the URL to "depth" or "homepage"` ?????

Comment: sry Roko i edited question in hopes that is more clear, ty for your time

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
var homepage = false;  //Direct links to NFL Homepages
var depth = true;  //Direct links to NFL Depthcharts
$(function() {
  if(homepage) 
  {
     $( ".depth" ).remove();
  }
  if(depth) 
  {
     $( ".homepage" ).remove();
  }
});
```